# How to pass strings from char array to a pointer char array?

Tags: c

I'm doing some practice on functions, pointers and arrays, and I'm having difficulty getting this program to run and compile. Basically I'm trying to declare an array, and then use a function to store values from the input array into a pointer char array, and then output the pointer array, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>





void cut_alphabet(char a[]); 
char convert(char b[]);


int main()
{

     char array[10][1000]; 
     int i; 

     for(i=0; i<10; i++)
     { 

         printf(" Please input a string value"); 
         fgets( array[i], 1000, stdin); 

     }

     convert(array[10]); 

     return 0; 

 }



 char convert(char b[])
 {

     int i;
     char *psentence[10][1000]; 


     for( i=0; i<10; i++)
     { 

        b[i] = &psentence[i];

        return psentence; 

     }
```

Comment: I'm curious. Why are you making many accounts?

Comment: FYI the program will be first compiled and then run.

Comment: I've posted questions asking for help on certain programs, and I've been downvoted and saying I couldn't post anymore. Even after only 3 posts. It's ridiculous

Comment: More explanation here: http://c-faq.com/malloc/retaggr.html

Comment: In function `convert`, variable `psentence` is a local array. There is no point returning it, and in fact, trying to use the return-value outside the function is unsafe (will lead to undefined behavior). You should allocate it dynamically (using `malloc`, for example). In addition, I believe that you want to remove the second dimension from the declaration of this variable, and change the type of the return value from `char` to `char**`.

Comment: The question ban is supposed to tell you to improve your question qulity, not to tell you to create another account.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: The statement "You aren't allowed to return variables declared locally in a function from the function" is incorrect (to say the least). You're allowed to return whatever you want. In the case of **local arrays**, using the return-value outside the function will lead to undefined behavior (so you may say it is "unallowed"). The value of any other type of local variable can be safely returned and used outside the function. The **address** of a local variable cannot.

Comment: Which book are you using that doesn't cover these things?

Comment: @barakmanos - You're right. I meant to say *arrays* not *variables* each time I used that word above. Just woke up a few minutes back :) The C-FAQ link is correct,though.

Comment: Downvoted, your question is badly written. In fact there isn't even a question in the text (and the title has a questionmark but doesn't make any sense). "I can't seem to get it to work" is not a question, nor a useful description. What isn't working?

Comment: And what's the idea behind passing `array[10]`?

Comment: @barakmanos - While I deleted my incorrect comment, I'd probably leave yours as it is. It is useful by itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong so bear with me:

```
int main() {

char array[10][1000]; // Ok, Note that you will use these ~10 kB of data for as long as the program runs.

int i; 

for(i=0; i < 10; i++) { 
    printf(" Please input a string value"); 
    fgets( array[i], 1000, stdin); 
}

// This next line has an error in your code, what you are saying here is:
// Send in the 11th string in "array", however array only has
// 10 strings so this will not work as intended.
// If you wish to send in ALL 10 strings just write convert(array)
// and change the function prototype to char ** convert(char array[][1000]). 
// Please note that the the [1000] must always match between the function and a 
// Statically allocated two-dimensional array. (One reason to prefer pointers 
// in this use-case.

 convert(array); 

 return 0;
```

}

I'm slightly uncertain about what you are actually trying to achieve here... Do you want to copy psentence into b? If so, what do you want psentence to be? Currently it is simply uninitialized data, which will appear like garbage in your code. If you instead want to convert the two dimensional array into an array of char-pointers, that makes a little more sense. So I will go with that...

**Assumptions**

- You do not know how many lines will be converted.
- The argument b[][] will live longer than the return value, therefore we do not need to duplicate the data.

Below are two different implementations performing basically the same thing, filling an array with pointers to the strings in b.

This version takes the array to store the elements as a parameter, 
This is required because we need the pointer-array to live even after we return from the function.
Also note that the return-value can be changed to void in this case.

```
void convert(char* ptr_arr[], char b[][1000], int lines ) {
   int i;
   for( i=0; i<lines; i++) {         
       ptr_arr[i] = b[i]; // b[i] yields a pointer to the i'th line.
   }
}
```

This version returns a new dynamically allocated array with the pointers.
Note that the allocated data must later be freed with a call to free.
Google dynamic memory allocation in C for more information.

```
char** convert(char b[][1000], int lines ) {
   char **ptr_arr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines +1 ); // Allocate enough space for lines +1 pointers.

   // Check that allocation succeeded. 
   if (ptr_arr == NULL) return NULL;

   int i;
   for( i=0; i<lines; i++) {         
       ptr_arr[i] = b[i]; 
   }
   // Use a NULL ptr to mark the last element (this is optional)
   ptr_arr[lines] = NULL;

   // Finally, return the new table:
   return ptr_arr;
}
```